# How to solve the error with cors and connect to the server?

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, strapi

I have my own domain and want to use socket io. but you give me an error with CORS policy

using Vue as strapi server

vue package.json

```
"socket.io": "^4.5.1",
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
"vue-3-socket.io": "^1.0.5",
```

vue main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from '@/store.js'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-3-socket.io'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(new VueSocketIO({
 debug: false,
 connection: SocketIO('https://my-domen/', options), //options object is Optional
 vuex: {
 store,
 actionPrefix: "SOCKET_",
 mutationPrefix: "SOCKET_"
 }
})
```

and throws an error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-domen/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O5js2pe' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:5000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this on your server.js file.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['your-domain-name]
    }
})
```

This is how I have set up for my project. hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).